# How to add labels to strings with letters in python list?

Tags: python, string, unique

I wrote some code that work fine but I would like to make it more precise.

The idea is to add a letter showing the occurence of the element in the list. The initial list look like this

```
['1','2','1','2','1']
```

And I want

```
['1a','2a','1b','2b','1c']
```

**I'm sure there is a quick answer or function to do this, does anyone have an idea ?**

My code below :

```
ancestrals = ['1','2','1','2','1']
uni_a = list(set(ancestrals))
for i in range(len(ancestrals)):
    tmp = uni_a.index(ancestrals[i])
    if uni_a[tmp][-1].isalpha():
        val = ancestrals[i][:1] + chr(ord(uni_a[tmp][-1])+1)
    else:
        val = ancestrals[i] + "a"

    ancestrals[i] = val

    while uni_a[tmp] in ancestrals[i:]:
        p = ancestrals[i:].index(uni_a[tmp])+ i
        ancestrals[p] = val

    uni_a[tmp] = ancestrals[i]
print(ancestrals)
```

Comment: If your code works but you want to see alternative solutions, then perhaps [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the better venue. I also did not downvote.

Comment: Thanks @JustinEzequiel, I didn't knew this comunity, will ask there in future occasions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ancestrals = ['1','2','1','2','1']

count = {}
for i, anc in enumerate(ancestrals):
    cnt = count.get(anc, 0)
    count[anc] = cnt + 1
    ancestrals[i] += chr(ord('a') + cnt)

print (ancestrals)
# --> ['1a', '2a', '1b', '2b', '1c']
```

Of course, that will only work if the maximum count per element is 26 (letter “z”).

Comment: Thanks ! Yes this limitation is known ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you want concise-but-a-bit-opaque, here is aa (admittedly tongue-in-cheek) version:

```py
from collections import Counter

def decorate(a):
    cnt = Counter()
    return [f'{x}{chr(ord("a") + i)}' for x in a for i in [cnt.update(x) or cnt[x] - 1]]
```

Example:

```py
>>> decorate(['1','2','1','2','1'])
['1a', '2a', '1b', '2b', '1c']
```

Comment: Thanks, I just want to limit dependencies in this case but this module seems very usefull !

Comment: sure, no dependencies except the standard library...

Answer (score 0):

While [the `Counter` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67199530/1431750) is nice, it is quite opaque, as @PierreD said.

Here's a clearer way to do it, while iterating over the `ancestrals` list and not modifying it in-place. The ordinal of the last letter used for each item is stored in the `last_letters` dictionary. For each `item`, it's checked and the next letter is used. The default is whatever is before `a` (`` ` `` backtick), so that you get 'a' when 1 is added to it.

```py
ancestrals = ['1','2','1','2','1']
last_letters = {}
uni_a = []  # will hold the result
default = ord('a') - 1  # char before 'a' is '`'

for item in ancestrals:
    prev_ord = last_letters.get(item, default)  # these two lines can be
    next_letter = chr(prev_ord + 1)             # combined into one
    uni_a.append(item + next_letter)
    last_letters[item] = prev_ord + 1

print(uni_a)
# ['1a', '2a', '1b', '2b', '1c']
```